# SQL-Java: Prepared Statement gives Index out of range Error

Tags: java, sql

I have the following code:

```
try {
        userPasswordNew = new String(ChangePW.passwordFieldconfirm.getPassword());
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET password = " + userPasswordNew + " WHERE username = " + username);
        prepStmt.setString(2, BCrypt.hashpw(userPasswordNew, BCrypt.gensalt(bcryptRounds))); //2 represents number of column in database starting with 0
        System.out.println(prepStmt);
        return prepStmt.executeUpdate() != 0;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

I tried 1 2 and 3 as indexes but everytime it throws an Index out of range exception. Is there another way to get the column, maybe adressed with its name? Or what am I doing wrong?
Could somebody please help?

Comment: You are not using `?` as parameter placeholders

Comment: uhm no, where is it missing?

Comment: You need `?` placeholders in your query string so they will be replaced by your parameters values (first occurence of `?` will be index 1, and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use prepared statements - please use `?` instead provided values. Like in this sample:

```
String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
```

To get more, please look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). In your case that could be:

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET password = ? WHERE username = ?");
prepStmt.setString(1, "that new password");
prepStmt.setString(2, "user_name");
```

Comment: Also make sure that the column data type matches string/varchar and if it is correct column number.

Comment: @zudokod - sure, but `username`, `password` should be strings - that is why I've skipped that part :)

Comment: ah now i got it. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I assume `password` and `username` are textual values. Hence you will have to enclose the values by quotes.

That is the query will be

```
"UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET password = " + userPasswordNew + " WHERE username = " + username
```

Also, as you are using PreparedStatement, you must not mention the variables in the query. A neater approach would be to use `?` instead. Something like this.

```
"UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET password = ? WHERE username = ?
```

And then use .setString() etc methods with `userPasswordNew` and `username`.

Check this, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

When you use `PreparedStatement`, you define the parameters to pass in the sql statement by placing 1 or more `?`.  
Then you pass values to these parameters with methods like `setString()`, `setInt()`,...  
The order of the parameters is not 0 based but 1 based.

```
    try {
        userPasswordNew = new String(ChangePW.passwordFieldconfirm.getPassword());
        PreparedStatement prepStmt =
                connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME +" SET password = ? WHERE username = ?");

        prepStmt.setString(1, userPasswordNew);
        prepStmt.setString(2, username);
        System.out.println(prepStmt);
        return prepStmt.executeUpdate() != 0;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In your code there is this line:

```
prepStmt.setString(2, BCrypt.hashpw(userPasswordNew, BCrypt.gensalt(bcryptRounds)));
```

I don't know if this is a parameter that you want to pass. 
If it is I can't see a `?` placeholder in the sql statement.